# Service for Bluetooth LE device discovery

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm not very experienced when it comes to implementing Android apps which make a lot of use of `Service`s and I couldn't find any good advice or examples to help me on SO or github (or by just googling) so I decided to ask my own question.

When my app is started, it needs to start discovering nearby Bluetooth LE beacon devices and it has to continue doing so at least until it's gone to the background. The only thing I need from these beacons is to get the basic data (like the UUID) of the one whose signal is the strongest.

**What is the best approach to achieve this?**

Currently I've got only got a regular `Service` which runs the `startLeScan()` method on `BluetoothAdapter` as soon as anything is bound to it. However, I've got more than 1 `Activity` in the app and I don't think binding to the `Service` and unbinding from it in each of them is the best thing to do. I thought about starting the `Service` instead of binding to it but then again stopping it could involve a lot of coding - it isn't exactly easy to determine when an Android app is put into background afaik.

Any hints and advice could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I don't consider myself an expert so feel free to correct me whenever I'm wrong.

I'm dumb - I didn't realise that the `startLeScan()` and `stopLeScan()` methods both take a `BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback` parameter and that this callback actually contains a method named `onLeScan()` called **asynchronously** upon a BluetoothLE device being scanned.

That means that no `Service` is necessary at all - it's enough to actually implement the `onLeScan()` method and it should do. I also put all of that in a singleton class instead so it's accessible from everywhere in the app.

I'll mark my answer as the correct one for now but do answer if you've got a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using iBeacons. Check out radius networks beacon library. It has a bunch of examples and instructions for how to download. Here is the link:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/pro/download.html

Included in the library are methods for discovering new beacons and easily getting there info (UUID, Major, minor, etc..). They even have examples showing how to do it.

Comment: That might be useful in case I've got some problems with the implementation. However, it looks like I only need a small portion of the functionality that library provides so I'd rather attempt to code it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, I recommend this iBeacon scanning app.

[BeaconBox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemustech.beaconbox)

It is useful for you to testing your beacons on smartphone.

I hope that you reach your goal.

Comment: That's useful for testing if my app finds all the devices I need it to and if it reads their profiles correctly. Thanks.